# Pascal error - ";" expected but Else found

Tags: syntax-error, pascal

I am using pascal to do an assignment but keep running into this error '";" expected but Else found'. I have seen many questions asking this and tried to use them to help myself but no luck.

My code

```
Program TeamWrite;  
    Var FName, txt : String[10];  
    UserFile : Text;  
BEGIN          
    FName := 'Team';  
    Assign(UserFile, 'C:\Team.dat');  
    Rewrite(UserFile);  
    Writeln('Enter players name and score separated by a space, type end to finish');  
    if txt = 'end' then;  
        BEGIN  
            Close(UserFile)  
        End;  
    Else  
        BEGIN  
            Readln(txt);  
            Writeln;  
            Writeln(UserFile,txt);  
        End;  
    Until(txt = 'end');  

End.
```

Answer (score 3):

In Pascal, semicolons (i.e. ";") are for separating statements, not ending them. So you should say:

```
if txt = 'end' then
  begin
    Close(UserFile)
  end
else
  begin
    Readln(txt);  
    Writeln;  
    Writeln(UserFile, txt)
  end
```

Note that there are no semicolons following `then`, preceding and following `else`, and following the two statements before `end`.

Also note that you can put a semicolon between a statement and an `end`, like:

```
begin
  WriteLn;
  WriteLn(txt);  <-- this is allowed
end
```

but the compiler would interpret it as if there is an empty statement following that semicolon:

```
begin
  WriteLn;
  WriteLn(txt);
  (an empty statement here)
end
```

which is harmless, though.

The "until" is an error, too, because it is a reserved word. In Pascal there is a "repeat...until" loop, like:

```
i := 0;
repeat
  WriteLn(i);
  i := i + 1
until i > 10
```

It's like C's "do...while" loop, only the condition is reversed. In your program I think you should have a `repeat` before the `if:

```
repeat
  if txt = 'end then
    ...
  else
    ...
until txt = 'end'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i have tried this out but now instead of the error being Else found it is now until found.

Comment: That's because "until" is a reserved word. Please see my edit above.

Comment: I took a closer look at your program and now I understand you're not calling a function named "Until". Please see my edit again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Pascal, but having a quick look through some websites I think you don't need the ; after the first if statement:

```
if txt = 'end' then;
```

should probably be

```
if txt = 'end' then
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced some `;`

```
if txt = 'end' then; // remove ';' 
    BEGIN  
        Close(UserFile) //add `;`
    End;  // remove ';' 
Else  
    BEGIN  
        Readln(txt);  
        Writeln;  
        Writeln(UserFile,txt);  
    End;  
Until(txt = 'end');
```

Please refer [here](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Else)